# React Native Navigation(StackNavigator): I get an error saying " undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigate') "

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native

I have just started learning react-native.... Doing a pet project now....
In the app there's a button on clicking it navigates to another screen. I get the following error saying " undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigate') "
The following are the files

index.js

```
  import React from "react";
  import Navigator from "./config/routes";
  export default () => <Navigator />;
```

The code  in my config/routes.js

```
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

import Home from "../screens/Home";
import List from "../screens/List";

export default StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: () => null
    }
  },
  List: {
     screen: List
  }
});
```

and my component file Home.js which has the button which on click clicking navigates to another screen

```
 /*all import statements*/
 class Home extends Component {
    handlePressBaseCurrency() {
       console.log("base currency button clicked");
       this.props.navigation.navigate("List"); /* error from this line */
    }
    render() {
            return (
                <UserInput
                    currencyShort={TEMP_BASE_CURRENCY}
                    onPress={this.handlePressBaseCurrency}
                    defaultValue={TEMP_BASE_PRICE}
                    keyboardType="numeric"
                    onChangeText={this.handleTextChange}
                />
            );
        }
 }
```

Please help!!! Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not bound correctly in `handlePressBaseCurrency`. You can:

1. Explicitly [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) `this` in your constructor:

   ```
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.handlePressBaseCurrency = this.handlePressBaseCurrency.bind(this);
   }
   ```
2. From the React Docs on [handling events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html):

   > If calling bind annoys you, there are two ways you can get around this. If you are using the experimental [public class fields syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/), you can use class fields to correctly bind callbacks:

   ```
   handlePressBaseCurrency = () => {
     console.log("base currency button clicked");
     this.props.navigation.navigate("List");
   };
   ```

Comment: You are welcome. You should accept this as the answer then